# JSON object not getting modified correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have very little experience in JS and I really could appreciate some insight into this anomaly and perhaps the solution.

I have a JSON dictionary being sent from server to the browser.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) {
        var dict_charts = response.dict_charts;
        $.each(dict_charts, function(key, value){
            $.each(value, function(k,v){
                const a = JSON.parse(dict_charts[key][k]['chart_config']);
                
                console.log(a['chart-config']['options']['scales']['xAxes']['0']['scaleLabel']);
                console.log(a['chart-config']['options']['scales']['xAxes']['0']);
                console.log(a);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```
===== Output Line 1 =====

scaleLabel has correct value(as in server)

   {display: true, labelString: "Count of Segment", padding: {…}, fontColor: "#d25656"}

 - display: true
 - fontColor: "#d25656"
 - labelString: "Count of Segment"
 - padding: {top: 4, bottom: 4}
 - __proto__: Object`


===== Output Line 2 =====

scaleLabel is undefined.

{display: false, position: "bottom", offset: false, gridLines: {…}, scaleLabel: {…}, …}      

 - display: false
 - id: "x-axis-0"
 - offset: false
 - position: "bottom"
 - scaleLabel: undefined
 - ticks: {beginAtZero: false, minRotation: 0, maxRotation: 50, mirror: false, padding: 15, …}    
 - type: "category"
 - __proto__: Object

===== Output Line 3 =====
```

scaleLabel value is incorrect.
Providing snapshot:
[Snippet of JSON object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAMp9.png)

scaleLabel details should be { 'display': true, ...}, but its not being mapped correctly.

Comment: According to your output, the scaleLabel is not undefined but an object when the output line is originally printed (`scaleLabel: {…} `), but when you expand the output line it shows undefined. This means that in the time between the output line was printed and you expanded it, it was set to undefined somewhere in your code (or in your chart library's code), because the devtools evaluate the newly displayed parts of the object only the moment you expand them! Try setting a breakpoint on the log statement and examining the object immediately to see what it really contained.

Comment: The lines of execution are exactly the same as is mentioned in the question. Another strange thing that I noticed was, when debugging line by line, ultimately the root dictionary object gets modified, but when I dont debug it, it remains unmodified. I am sharing a video link in case I didn't explain it clearly. [link](https://youtu.be/op37PSMIfQ0)

Comment: Look, the thing is: The moment you expand an object in the console (you click the ►), the contents are evaluated again and printed. The first time, you did as I said, and you looked at the object _before_ the rest of the code ran. The second time, you looked at it _after_ the rest of the code ran. So, something in the code is modifying it!

Comment: To see illustrated what I mean, look at this: https://recordit.co/9xrTz3Ip18 - The first time, I expand a line that reads `{ a: 1, ... }` but in the expanded view, it shows `a: 2`! This is because at the time I click ►, the value had already changed! But the second time, I am debugging it and I'm clicking the ► _before_ the `a` changes.

Comment: Btw, seeing in the video that you do use a debugger earned you my upvote. 

Comment: I got the solution... in another place in my code, the innermost array structure was getting converted to a dictionary. Had to change it back to an array format. Now I am getting the data mapped correctly. Thanks a lot for your help @CherryDT